# Prevent multiple submits with Javascript and Prototype

Tags: javascript, html, forms, prototypejs

I try to prevent multiple submits in HTML forms using Javascript through Prototype API. Here is the snippet I use to solve this problem :

```
function preventMultipleSubmits() {
    this.select('input[type="submit"]').invoke('disable');
    return true;
}

document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
    var forms = $A(document.getElementsByTagName('form'));
    forms.each(function(form) {
        form.observe('submit', preventMultipleSubmits)
    });
});
```

The problem with that snippet is that submitting a form doesn't call the server side anymore. I know that IE browsers doesn't support CCS selectors very well, but the problem concerns Firefox too, and I'd like to focus on FF first.

The environnement and tools :

- Firefox 13.0
- Prototype 1.6.1

Comment: Seems to work just fine (in Chrome and Firefox) http://jsfiddle.net/jZx6P/1/

Comment: Thanks for your post. I didn't know the site you mentioned. I'll try to rely on jsfiddle to find a clue.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.select('input[type="submit"]').invoke('disable');
```

This appears to just add the disabled attribute to the `submit` button. You can still get it to submit with enter for one-field forms.

You might try something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function preventMultipleSubmits(event) {
    if (this.hasClassName('allow-one-time-submit')) {
        this.removeClassName('allow-one-time-submit');
        // don't stop the event
    } else {
        alert('You already submitted');
        event.stop();
    }
}

document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
    var forms = $A(document.getElementsByTagName('form'));
    forms.each(function(form) {
        // add Class Name to each and every form on load
        form.addClassName('allow-one-time-submit');
        form.observe('submit', preventMultipleSubmits)
    });

});
</script>


<form action="http://www.example.com/path/to/action" class="allow-one-time-submit">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Hi Artlung, thanks for your tip. Your remark is relevant, and I will consider it. But the problem is I have to deal with existing code, so adding a class name to any of my numerous forms is not an option.

Comment: Ah, well, easy enough to add a function on load which adds the className to every form.

Comment: @1tox I went ahead and added the code to add the class to each form.